# Putting Anaconda pip onto Flash drive and installing off it

Tags: python, download, pip, installation, anaconda

I am unable to install pip normally because of a proxy at work.  I am going to use a flash drive to transfer it onto the computer.  Is it possible to put just pip onto a flashdrive and transfer it onto different computer to install? If so how?

Comment: Do you need to install PIP itself or are you unable to use PIP to install a package from the internet due to the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to install PIP and you mean you can't use PIP in it's normal method to download/install a package from the internet, you can download the package onto a flash drive and then do:

```
pip install /dir/package
```

Comment: I was able to install anaconda but the command: $conda install pip      does not work because of the proxyError.   EDIT: installing pip is my problem essentially

Comment: Not sure why you're trying to install pip through anaconda or am I misunderstanding?

If you need to install through anaconda offline then do 

    conda install something --use-index-cache

after properly downloading the package

Answer (score 0):

You can install `Anaconda` to virtualenv and write your venv to flashdrive or write only site-packages/anaconda folder to flash drive